# Image doesn’t load consistently from Azure blob storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I am having an erratic problem using Azure blob storage where my images do not load consistently. The problem is that sometimes when I load a web page, the browser will not show the image, but if I refresh it will load correctly.

When the image doesn't load, the browser shows the default image placeholder. Here is an example:

If I check the hyperlink for the image placeholder, I find that it is the same as the when the image loads successfully, except the Shared Access Signature is different.

Sometimes the same image will fail to load for one link but load successfully for another link even in the same page and same page load. The only difference in the URL is the Shared Access Signature.

Here is my code to build the URL with the shared signature

```
// Get reference to blob (file) that is to be downloaded
blob = blobContainer.GetBlobReference(blobURL.ToString());

// Get shared access signature to download file from azure blob (valid upto "active duration" minutes) from now
signature = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessPolicy()
{
SharedAccessStartTime = null,
SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60), 
Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Read
});

// Append signature query string to blob / file that is to be downloaded
downloadURL = string.Format("{0}{1}", blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri, signature);
```

This is the final HTML image link on the web page, i.e. if I show source on the web page in the browser:

```
<img alt="Profile Picture" src="https://mystorageaccount2.blob.core.windows.net/abcdefg1-hi23-40b5-86de-a20b568f5626/1601/1234d664d1b74ce1aebf4403e5b74af7.jpg?se=2015-10-31T11%3A38%3A39Z&amp;sr=b&amp;sp=r&amp;sig=SaiUToJg%5Ab3zcdef8EeOq84urHf6HQqS%2BAFt1dEQMNI%3D">
```

Has anyone else seen this problem? Any recommendations on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this could be related to the expiry period which you have set on your image blob's shared access signature (SAS). Is there any good reason where you need to set the SAS to 1 minute when you have set it's permission to read-only?

Comment: Hi Juvchan. I appreciate your response. I think the DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60) method will set the timeout to 1 hour, which is the maximum amount allowed for Azure table storage. I just doublechecked it and I think that is still accurate. Also, the page is loading and I am looking for the image immediately, so even if it was 1 minute I would expect to see the image.

Comment: Hi @Xethnic, sorry for mistaken the SAS expiry period. When your webpage does not show the image, does the image blob Uri generated or not?

Comment: Yes. The url for the img src is correct and the SAS looks correct.